# A SQL query for a running total of users

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

This query:

```
SELECT received_at as sign_up_date,
   COUNT(DISTINCT email) AS "count"
FROM seller_v2.users
  GROUP BY 1
  ORDER BY 1;
```

Creates the following output:

```
sign_up_date                count
2016-02-18T17:38:51.000Z      1
2016-02-18T21:47:48.000Z      1
```

Each date equals the signup date of a user. How do I create a a new column with a running total of users so that I can create a time series chart?

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: ..And do you want this by calendar day, or the timestamp you're currently using?

Comment: Sorry. Using Redshift.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using SQL Server (I believe syntax is the same for Oracle and possibly some other RDBMSes) you can use [`ROW_NUMBER()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) for displaying the row number, which in your case is identical to running total:

```
SELECT received_at as sign_up_date,
   ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY received_at ASC) AS running_total
FROM seller_v2.users;
```